# Signalr not always run OnDisconnected after timeout

Tags: signalr, .net-4.8

I'm using SignalR 2.2.2 and discovered that from time to time in my Hub OnDisconnected method is not fired.
So is it possible in case there is no connection to the client Hub forgets to close the connection?

Comment: It's probably reconnecting. There are three separate protocols being used in signalr. Depending on what occurs, it may not have to disconnect and give you a new connection id. It will simply reconnect internally and reuse the same connection id

Comment: @GHDevOps thanks for the comment. There were just several disconnects and reconnects, all-time it was WebSocket transport, and after last connect didn't see the disconnect, for me looks like after some period of time because of load SignalR forgets for some connections.